# Pivot data table

Tags: pivot

I am a novice user of SQL, I would like to pivot my data to look like the table on the right 'NEW', the current database view from my query is the left table 'OLD'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVRKT.gif)

OLD

```
ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE   GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP   VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP
24/08/2017 0:00                 -0.144960562            0.258170852
23/08/2017 0:00                 -0.143660442            0.258379336
22/08/2017 0:00                 -0.145358176            0.259934845
21/08/2017 0:00                 -0.14478461         0.260095044
```

NEW

```
ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE   FACTOR                  VALUE
24/08/2017 0:00                 GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP   -0.144960562
23/08/2017 0:00                 GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP   -0.143660442
22/08/2017 0:00                 GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP   -0.145358176
21/08/2017 0:00                 GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP   -0.14478461
24/08/2017 0:00                 VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP    0.258170852
23/08/2017 0:00                 VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP    0.258379336
22/08/2017 0:00                 VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP    0.259934845
21/08/2017 0:00                 VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP    0.260095044
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic SQL solution here would be to just use a `UNION` to structure the output that you want.  Here, we introduce the `FACTOR` label column depending on the value column we select in that record (i.e. either `GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP` or `VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP`.

```
SELECT
    ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE,
    'GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP' AS FACTOR,
    GROWTH_ACTIVE_EXP AS VALUE
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE,
    'VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP',
    VALUE_ACTIVE_EXP AS VALUE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    ENGINE_ASOF_CALENDAR_DATE,
    FACTOR
```